# NITE2::UserTracker crashes when reading from oni files

Tags: c++, kinect, openni, kinect-sdk, nite

I have recorded an oni file using a kinect and OpenNI NIViewer.

I want to track skeletons in that record file so I am using OpenNI2 and NITE2

I can create an openi device with the oni file but when I try to create a nite2 user tracker using that device it crashes and I get the following error:

> 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000000000004c

On the cmd window I got the following message:

> Couldn't getXN_STREAM_PROPERTY_PARAM_COEFF

Here is my code:

```
openni::Status rc = openni::OpenNI::initialize();
openni::Device device ;
rc = device.open("file.oni");
nite::UserTracker userTracker;
nite::NiTE::initialize();
niteRc = userTracker.create(&device);
```

Any Help is largely appreciated.

Could you please also advise if there are any other ways to track selections in recorded oni files?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced your same problem.

I recorded the oni files with the OpenNI2 sample NiViewer. The recorded file can be loaded using NiViewer itself (therefore the file is not corrupt), but if I try to open the saved file with the Nite2 sample UserViewer, I experience your same error.

The only way I've found to solve the problem id downgrading from Nite 2.2 to Nite 2.0 (as suggested in [Creating a UserTracker crashes in NITE2 python bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962339/creating-a-usertracker-crashes-in-nite2-python-bindings))

The strange thing is that I tested this saving/loading procedure with both Kinect and Asus Xtion, but I had this problem only with Kinect savings.